# React.createElement("audio", ... is not working? What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

The 1st version does not work, the images do not show. No errors, just nothing displays

```
const grid_display = ({ url, key }) =>
React.createElement("audio", { id: "woof", src: "https://free-screensavers-backgrounds.com/ringtones/funny/dog-barking.mp3"},
React.createElement("div", { onMouseOver: "playSound('woof')", className: "image-item", key: key },
React.createElement("a", { href: "https://www.google.com"},
React.createElement("img", { className: "grid-img", src: url }))));
```

This 2nd version does work! The images display as expected.

```
 const grid_display = ({ url, key }) =>
 React.createElement("div", {className: "image-item", key: key },
 React.createElement("a", { href: "https://www.google.com"},
 React.createElement("img", { className: "grid-img", src: url })));
```

Anyone have a reason why the createElement audio causes the issue?

PS. The end result is displaying images in a grid. I need each image to play a sound when you mouse over them. NOTE: The images/sounds are actually dynamic.

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It does create, you can check the `html` code using browser dev tools.You have not added the `controls` attribute, because of which it is not visible in the `html`.

```
const grid_display = ({ url, key }) =>
React.createElement("audio", { id: "woof", controls: "controls", src: "https://free-screensavers-backgrounds.com/ringtones/funny/dog-barking.mp3"},
React.createElement("div", { onMouseOver: "playSound('woof')", className: "image-item", key: key },
React.createElement("a", { href: "https://www.google.com"},
React.createElement("img", { className: "grid-img", src: url }))));
```

### Demo

```js
const audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.src = "https://free-screensavers-backgrounds.com/ringtones/funny/dog-barking.mp3";
// audio element added but not visible in html
//audio.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
document.body.append(audio);

const showAudio = document.createElement('audio');
showAudio.src = "https://free-screensavers-backgrounds.com/ringtones/funny/dog-barking.mp3";
// Now visible
showAudio.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
document.body.append(showAudio);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I play the sound when the image has mouse over event?

Comment: randomSoul, so you gave me another idea :)
Which is to put the audio control right below the image. So I don't need the mouse over event, BUT I do need the React.createElement to write out the control.

In my OP, the "const grid_display" is actually called in a loop (infinite grid).
Do you know how to add the control via a createElement statement?

Comment: @user1864734 - I don't have much idea about `react`. You can create `audio` element separately, and then append to body or any other element.